# Windows with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I started studying Python last Monday. I tried to create a window using tkinter. Pycharm says there are no mistakes but after running the code the window doesn't appear D:
That's my code

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("thecharmii")
window.geometry("700x500")
window.config(background = "black")

window.mainloop()
```

I downloaded the latest Python version, I guess it's 3.10. When I click on Run the window doesn't appear but it looks like the process is still running. Thanks for the help

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code works fine for me. (Using idle, not pycharm).

Comment: Try executing the script in a console/terminal.  If it works, then it is the issue of PyCharm.

Comment: I tried with idle and it worked, thanks! I don't know why my Pycharm is acting out -.-

Comment: btw, since you just have started out it would about time you get out of the habit of using `*` when importing (basically don't use `from some_module import *`), especially as you just start out it could lead to hard-to-debug issues because of name clashes, so you can either do sth like `from tkinter impot Tk, Frame, Label` and go like that or sth like `import tkinter` and then later use it as `window = tkinter.Tk()`, however you can also use an alias like `import tkinter as tk` and then use as `window = tk.Tk()`. The last two approaches also help with understanding where the name comes from

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("thecharmii")
    window.geometry("700x500")
    window.config(background = "black")

    window.mainloop()

    
main()
```